# Vue routes usable by Laravel routes

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

When I refresh the page when navigating through my VueJS routes, the server throws me an error because the routes are not defined in `routes/web.php`.

This is what I've tried to catch the routes:

```
Route::get('/mealPlansV2/{catchall?}', 'MealPlansV2Controller@index');
Route::get('/menusV2/{catchall?}', 'OrdersController@index');
```

I have 2 modules 'meal plans' and 'menus', that's why I created two separate routes.

Comment: what is vue router mode ?

Comment: @RishiRaut what do you mean ?